# SlideShowWindows error (integer out of range)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm preparing a quiz using on PowerPoint using the controllers of VBA scripts. My aim to set multiple questions, each has 4 choices.

I've set everything, when trying to run (starting with the method: "BeginQuiz") it's interrupted by the following error:

> SlideShowWindows (unknown number) Integer out of range

My code is below:

```
Const NOOFQS = 4

'Used to manipulated the unicode values of bulleted lists
Const UD_CODE_1 = 111
Const UD_CODE_2 = 8226

Public QNo As Integer
Public ExitFlag As Boolean
Public Qs() As String
Public Choices() As String
Public Ans() As Integer
Public UserAns() As Integer

Sub NextSlide()
' Store the ans for later
'UserAns(QNo - 1) = 1
If QNo < NOOFQS Then
    QNo = QNo + 1
    SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides("QSlide").Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Qs(QNo - 1)
    AssignValues
Else
    Call StopQuiz
End If
DoEvents
End Sub
Sub PreviousSlide()
Static X As Integer
If QNo > 1 Then
    QNo = QNo - 1
    AssignValues
End If
End Sub
Sub StopQuiz(Optional EndType As Boolean = False)
' EndType is used as a boolean Flag to indicate whether the user ran out of time
' or whether it was normal exit
Dim ScoreCard As Integer
Dim Ctr As Integer
ExitFlag = True
With SlideShowWindows(1)
For Ctr = 0 To NOOFQS - 1
    If Ans(Ctr) = UserAns(Ctr) Then ScoreCard = ScoreCard + 1
Next Ctr
If EndType = False Then
    .Presentation.Slides("EndSlide").Shapes("Closing").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Your score is : " & ScoreCard & " correct out of " & NOOFQS
Else
    .Presentation.Slides("EndSlide").Shapes("Closing").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Sorry!!! Either you ran out of time or you chickened out" _
            & vbCrLf & "Better luck next time." & vbCrLf _
            & "Your score is: " & ScoreCard & " correct out of " & NOOFQS
End If
    .View.GotoSlide (.Presentation.Slides("EndSlide").SlideIndex)
End With
End Sub

Sub StopIt()
Call StopQuiz(True)
End Sub

Sub BeginQuiz()
Dim Ctr As Integer
ReDim Qs(NOOFQS)
ReDim Ans(NOOFQS)
ReDim UserAns(NOOFQS)
ReDim Choices(NOOFQS, 4)

' All the questions
Qs(0) = "1) ãä Ãæá ãä ÝÊÍ ÇáÞÏÓ ÈÚÏ ÚãÑ¿"
Qs(1) = "2) ãä åí Ãæá ãä ÃÓáãÊ ãä ÇáäÓÇÁ¿"
Qs(2) = "3) ãÇ åí ÇáãäØÞÉ ÇáÊí ÍÑÑåÇ ãÍãÏ ÇáÝÇÊÍ¿"
Qs(3) = "4) ãÇ åæ Ãæá ãÓÌÏ Ýí ÇáÅÓáÇã¿"

' Set all user answers to negative
For Ctr = 0 To NOOFQS - 1
UserAns(Ctr) = -1
Next Ctr

' All the choices 3 each for a question
Choices(0, 0) = " ÕáÇÍ ÇáÏíä ÇáÃíæÈí"
Choices(0, 1) = " ÇáÞÇÆÏ ÇáãÙÝÑ"
Choices(0, 2) = " ÎÇáÏ Èä ÇáæáíÏ"
Choices(0, 3) = " ÇáÙÇåÑ ÈíÈÑÓ"

Choices(1, 0) = " ÃÓãÇÁ ÈäÊ ÃÈí ÈßÑ "
Choices(1, 1) = " ÓæÏÉ ÈäÊ ÒãÚÉ "
Choices(1, 2) = " ÎÏíÌÉ ÈäÊ ÎæíáÏ "
Choices(1, 3) = "  Ãã ÚãÇÑ Èä íÇÓÑ "

Choices(2, 0) = " ØáíØáÉ "
Choices(2, 1) = " ÇáÞÇÏÓíÉ "
Choices(2, 2) = " ÇáÞÓØäØíäíÉ "
Choices(2, 3) = " ÇáÃäÏáÓ"

Choices(3, 0) = " ãÓÌÏ ÞÈÇÁ"
Choices(3, 1) = " ãÓÌÏ Ðí ÇáäæÑíä"
Choices(3, 2) = " ÇáãÓÌÏ ÇáäÈæí"
Choices(3, 3) = " ÇáÈíÊ ÇáÍÑÇã"

' Provide the answer list here.
' Ans(0) = 0 means that the correct answer to the 1st question is the 1st choice.
' Ans(1) = 1 means that the correct answer to the 2nd question is the 2nd choice.
' Ans(2) = 1 means that the correct answer to the 3rd question is the 2nd choice.

Ans(0) = 0
Ans(1) = 2
Ans(2) = 2
Ans(3) = 0

QNo = 1
AssignValues

With SlideShowWindows(1)
    .View.GotoSlide (.Presentation.Slides("QSlide").SlideIndex)
End With
' Comment the line below to stop the timer.
Call Tmr
End Sub

Sub SetBulletUnicode(ShapeName As String, Code As Integer)
With SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides("QSlide").Shapes(ShapeName).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
        .UseTextFont = msoTrue
        .Character = Code
End With
End Sub
Sub ButtonChoice1()
UserAns(QNo - 1) = 0
AssignValues
End Sub
Sub ButtonChoice2()
UserAns(QNo - 1) = 1
AssignValues
End Sub
Sub ButtonChoice3()
UserAns(QNo - 1) = 2
AssignValues
End Sub

Sub Tmr()

'Just in the eventuality that you click the start button twice
'isRunning stores the current state of the macro
'TRUE = Running; FALSE = Idle
ExitFlag = False
Static isRunning As Boolean
If isRunning = True Then
    End
Else
    isRunning = True
    Dim TMinus As Integer
    Dim xtime As Date
    xtime = Now

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("Timer")

    'Countdown in seconds
    TMinus = 59

    Do While (TMinus > -1)
    DoEvents
        ' Rather crude way to determine if a second has elapsed
        If ExitFlag = True Then
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "00:00:00"
            isRunning = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Format(Now, "ss") <> Format(xtime, "ss") Then
            xtime = Now

           .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(TimeValue(Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")) - _
                               TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Minute(Now), Second(Now) + TMinus), "hh:mm:ss")
            TMinus = TMinus - 1
            ' Let the display refresh itself
        End If
    Loop
    End With
    Debug.Print "came here"
    isRunning = False
    StopQuiz True
    End
End If
End Sub
Sub AssignValues()
    SetBulletUnicode "Choice1", UD_CODE_1
    SetBulletUnicode "Choice2", UD_CODE_1
    SetBulletUnicode "Choice3", UD_CODE_1
    SetBulletUnicode "Choice4", UD_CODE_1

    Select Case UserAns(QNo - 1)
    Case 0
        SetBulletUnicode "Choice1", UD_CODE_2
    Case 1
        SetBulletUnicode "Choice2", UD_CODE_2
    Case 2
        SetBulletUnicode "Choice3", UD_CODE_2
     Case 3
        SetBulletUnicode "Choice4", UD_CODE_2
    End Select
    With SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides("QSlide")
        .Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Qs(QNo - 1)
        .Shapes("Choice1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Choices(QNo - 1, 0)
        .Shapes("Choice2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Choices(QNo - 1, 1)
        .Shapes("Choice3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Choices(QNo - 1, 2)
        .Shapes("Choice4").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Choices(QNo - 1, 3)
    End With
End Sub

Sub ShowAnswers()
    Dim AnsList As String
    AnsList = "The answers are as follows:" & vbCrLf
    For X = 0 To NOOFQS - 1
        AnsList = AnsList & Qs(X) & vbTab & " Answer:" & Choices(X, Ans(X)) & vbCrLf
    Next X
    MsgBox AnsList, vbOKOnly, "Correct answers"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the presentation in slide show view when the problem code runs?  If not, that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry ... What do you mean ... I have three slides (introduction with button to run StartQuiz Method) and the second one has the form of question and choices and the third one is the form that shows the score of student :)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many slides you have. If you're not in slide show view, there will be no SlideShowWindows.  If you've opened the presentation and see the usual ribbon and other controls, you're not in slide show view.

Comment: Thanks! I know that ... but when I turn the choices to be JUST three the problem disappear ... That's made me confused :(